# Spring Security login.. redirection to another jsp page

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, spring-security

(sorry for my english)
I'm new in Spring Security, and I need, just when my user is logged, that the application redirection to another page, but aparently, I have no permission, and i'm getting error "HTTP Status 404 - /springsecurity/medicoPaciente.jsp".. i dont know what to do.. My code is:

spring-security.xml

```
*<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd">


    <http auto-config="true">
        <intercept-url pattern="/admin**" access="ROLE_USER" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/vistaPacientet**" access="ROLE_GUEST" />
        <form-login login-page="/login" default-target-url="/medico"
            authentication-failure-url="/login?error" username-parameter="username"
            password-parameter="password" />
            <form-login login-page="/login" default-target-url="/medview/**"
            authentication-failure-url="/login?error" username-parameter="username"
            password-parameter="password" />
        <logout logout-success-url="/login?logout" />
        <csrf />
    </http>

    <authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider>
            <user-service>
                <user name="mau" password="1" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
            </user-service>
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>

</beans:beans>*
```

I think, here is where i have to declare all the jsp..
Please help me :(

Comment: Does 'medicoPaciente.jsp' exist in _/webapp/WEB-INF/springsecurity/_? Please provide more information about your directory structure and please post any MVC controllers.

Comment: Not related to OP's question, but why dont you try it from here.. http://appfuse.org/display/APF/AppFuse+QuickStart  . Here you can create a spring mvc project with all the inbuild configurations

Comment: What you have included is the spring security configuration (why do you have form login twice?). You also need to include and configure Spring MVC (web.xml and it's application context), have you done that? And if so include it in your question so we can take a look at it.

Comment: its embarassing.. it was just a extra / in a path.. :s sorry